# How to delete Index Name for both row and columns ? (axis=0 & axis=1)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

In a personal project I played with a dataframe and had something like this

```py
In[1] : 
from random import random

companies = ['Google', 'Apple', 'Nike', 'Microsoft']
Years = [2020, 2019, 2018]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Company', 'Year', 'Money'])
iterator = 0

for company in companies:
    for year in Years:
        df.loc[iterator] = [company, year, random()]
        iterator += 1

df.set_index('Year').pivot(columns='Company', values='Money')

Out[1]:
Company Apple   Google  Microsoft   Nike
Year                
2018    0.290925    0.568462    0.459147    0.755947
2019    0.919250    0.529112    0.881319    0.700846
2020    0.064253    0.742629    0.232048    0.522739
```

I would like to get ride of `Company` & `Year` so my output becomes

```py
Out[2]:
        Apple   Google  Microsoft   Nike

2018    0.290925    0.568462    0.459147    0.755947
2019    0.919250    0.529112    0.881319    0.700846
2020    0.064253    0.742629    0.232048    0.522739
```

I know that the Raw Index name can be removed like this:

```
del df.index.name
```

But how to remove the columns index name ?

Comment: `df=df.rename_axis(None,axis=1)` ?

Comment: try df = `df.reset_index()`. Please add some example input and output data for better responses.

Comment: This only removes the `raw_index_name`.
But better than how I did, using `del` is not really nice

Comment: for col index use `axis=1` , check comment above

Comment: `del df.columns.name` ?

Comment: It does work, all answers so far works.Even though I prefer @Scott Bostons's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using:

```
del df.columns.name
```

or both at the same time using

```
df.rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
```

So, at then end of your pivot statement, chain the `rename_axis` method like this:

```
df = df.set_index('Year').pivot(columns='Company', values='Money')\
       .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
```

Output:

```
         Apple    Google  Microsoft      Nike
2018  0.491759  0.102509   0.799196  0.603748
2019  0.640801  0.966476   0.401801  0.928443
2020  0.678182  0.373457   0.524619  0.389381
```

Answer (score 1):

Just rename columns and index to `None`

```
df.columns.name, df.index.name = None, None
```

Result

```
        Apple       Google      Microsoft   Nike
2018    0.385702    0.402060    0.649404    0.640924
2019    0.999002    0.869702    0.129008    0.082098
2020    0.993765    0.402157    0.902664    0.774389
```